# Background image, mobiles and media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm trying to make it responsive to mobiles. I have background image that won't correctly resize. I've tried a media query and have no idea why it doesn't work. My code if below;

```css
.container3{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 700px;
  text-shadow: 0.25px 0.25px 0.25px #000000;
  background-image: url('Images/homepage.jpg');
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}

@media all and (max-width:480px)and(min-width:0px) {
  .container3 {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('Images/homepage.jpg');
  }
}
```

```html
<html> 
  <title>Unity</title>
  <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=500, initial-scale=1">
  <body>

    <div class="container3">
      <div class="title">
        <h1>
          bringing people together
        </h1>
        <p>free advertising space</p>

      </div> 
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you check http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp or try to use max-width instead of width

Comment: We can't help because your example code is broken. For the missing image use a service like http://placehold.it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.container3{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 700px;
  text-shadow: 0.25px 0.25px 0.25px #000000;
  background-image: url('Images/homepage.jpg');
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}

@media all and (max-width:888px) {
  .container3 {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://feelgrafix.com/data/background/background-17.jpg');
  }
}
```

```html
<html> 
  <title>Unity</title>
  <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=500, initial-scale=1">
  <body>

    <div class="container3">
      <div class="title">
        <h1>
          bringing people together
        </h1>
        <p>free advertising space</p>

      </div> 
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

It doesnt work because the syntax is wrong, you should use spaces in `@media all and (max-width:480px)and(min-width:0px)`. like this:`@media all and (max-width:480px) and (min-width:0px)`  also, it is redundant, since a device will always have more than 0px width, so you can delete the second part.

I used `max-width:888px` so you can see the sample img in the snippet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input you've got me up and running again! Thanks a lot! :)